# Two Column Layout. Why one is Float:Left and Another Float:Right?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I see when two columns layout is used (main content and sidebar) main content DIV  is Float:left and Sidebar is Float:right. 
I see one benefits of it. When  box-sizing: content-box; (default) is used then more than required space is left for fitting together and then both float opposite so that it in any trouble, both fits on screen! I see sometimes, when wrapper is more than the combined witdh (which is left so that they fit together) of Sidebar and content then space between sidebar and content is more than desired. This depends on Browser as well.

But with "box-sizing: border-box;" I see both fit exactly as expected even without leaving any extra space between both Div.

**Which is better and why?**

```
<div id="content">
With CSS: Float:left;
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
With CSS: Float:right;
</div>
```

Or,

```
<div id="content">
With CSS: Float:left;
</div>

<div id="sidebar">
With CSS: Float:left;
</div>
```

Think of responsive design as well.

Comment: `float:left;` means you have to worry about the margin between them. Using `float:right` means you don't. I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is better than the other. They behave differently but can under some conditions produce the same results.

**Scenarios when floating one container to the right is great:**

- If the sidebar is on the left side of the content you'd need to place it before the content in your markup if both `float` to the left. This isn't ideal for SEO purposes. If you `float` in both directions it doesn't matter where they appear in the markup.
- If you need the right element to align to the far right side you should `float` it to the right. You can't do it if boat `float` to the left, because different browser engines render sub pixels in different ways. Some layouts may look horrible even if it's just a few pixels off.
- As a continuation to the last point, you don't really want two elements with `width: 50%`. A slightly lower percentage than 50, like 49.9%, is to be preferred because of, again, sub pixel rounding. To avoid a scewed layout you'll probably want to `float` the right element to the right.

**Scenarios when floating both elements to the same side may be better:**

- When both elements should be aligned next to each other.
- Can't really think of anything else.

I usually `float` the right element to the right, but they're very often interchangeable.

Comment: One more reason to ask is because content in sidebar and content in main content div should be at equal distance from the common border. Using float at opposite direction sometimes distance are not equal. But it looks according to your point, it is best to float on opposite direction and use wrapper to contain both "content" and sidebar div at right distance.

Comment: While I understand it may not be reasonable depending on the layout, but even if you `float` one element to the right you could still control the distance between a separator with `padding`. But then again, it doesn't really matter.